# how to add 0 in for loop in JavaScript by alerting the variable

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

i'm trying to add *zero(0)* in this `for` loop using JavaScript here is my code:

```
for(var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {

alert(i);}
```

how to add or alert 5,4,3,2,1,0 in this code, i'm only getting 5,4,3,2,1 and it's done.

Comment: This is something that should be covered by a tutorial. Use `>=`.

Comment: what do you mean by add zero(0)?

Comment: i want to  alert the (i) that show 5,4,3,2,1,0 every time i loop the (i) but i'm getting only 5,4,3,2,1 in the browser once you run the code, i want the complete number to pop up including zero,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you just want to add zero(0) literally to all your input, you will have this:

```js
for(var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
  alert (i);}
```

Comment: antzshrek Thank you!!

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help appreciate that :)

Comment: Happy that I was able to be of help to you.